# Is Tassimo's caramel creamer suppose to be chunky?

Tags: coffee, drinks

I got some Tassimos caramel creamer, the t-disc style, and I was wondering if anyone knows if it is suppose to be chunky?

Answer (score 1):

If it's the one for caramel latte, or similar, then no. It can go wrong without smelling wrong and the date (which is a best before date anyway) is on the outer packaging which you've probably discarded. It's not my sort of drink but I had some for others, which meant it was hanging around too long.

If there were lumps of caramel in there they'd melt as soon as they got in a hot drink.